# How to check an NFS export's availablity using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, networking, nfs

How can I check if an NFS share on network is online/available/alive using Ruby code (on Linux)?

I have a code like this at the moment:

```
while !Ping.pingecho('192.168.1.116')
end
`mount -a`
exec 'SOMETHING THAT IS PLACED ON NFS SHARE'
```

And it doesn't work quite OK, because the remote machine exporting the share don't always have the NFS service ready as soon as it goes online on network. That is; it responds to pings but; I'm unable to mount it unless the NFS service starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command

```
rpcinfo -u 192.168.1.116 nfs 3
```

and check the return status. This invokes NFS procedure 0 on `192.168.1.116`, which essentially is an RPC ping. You should redirect stdout and stderr somewhere, as this command apparently has no quiet mode.

Comment: I hate to say this but; rpcinfo command is not supported on the platform I'm working with...

Comment: if you bypass the portmapper (which you can, since NFS uses fixed ports, anyway), writing this rpcinfo call in pure ruby shouldn't be too difficult. It's just a single, fixed UDP packet which you can sniff and hard-code, and you just have to look at a few bits of the reply if you get any. Assuming the NFS server supports TCP, just creating a TCP connection may be sufficient.